# My code cannot update nested component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I try React and react-typist.

I have some problem.
Then I pass a closure that change the state, to "onTypingDone" and called it, but not working correctly.
I think that because Typist may not re-render inner components.
For example, the following code. The following code does not work well.

How can I works correctly?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Typist from 'react-typist';

export interface Props {}
export interface State {
    className: string
}

export MyComponents extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = { className: "before" };
    }

    switch() {
        this.setState({ className: "after" });
    }

    render()
    {
        <Typist onTypingDone={this.switch.bind(this)}>
            <div className={this.state.className}>
                <p>Hello.</p>
            </div>
        </Typist>
    }
}
```

Comment: oh sorry it is mistype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I dive into the code found the real issue, 
Typist is stopping the re-render,

this.state.className is pointing to the MyComponents,
But content within Typist is not re-rendering, 
Reason is `shouldComponentUpdate` function inside Typist component

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextState.textLines.length !== this.state.textLines.length) {
        return true;
    }
    for (let idx = 0; idx < nextState.textLines.length; idx++) {
        const line = this.state.textLines[idx];
        const nextLine = nextState.textLines[idx];
            if (line !== nextLine) {
                return true;
            }
    }
    return this.state.isDone !== nextState.isDone;
}
```

> shouldComponentUpdate :
>
> render() will not be invoked if shouldComponentUpdate() returns false.

You can achieve the solution by this way :

```
<div className={this.state.className}>
    <Typist onTypingDone={this.switch.bind(this)}>
            <p>Hello.</p>
    </Typist>
</div>
```